# How reference source without having to use the entire destination path?

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a file that copies itself using:

```
/y C:\Users\user\Desktop\big.bat F:\
```

I would like to be able to copy the file without having to refer to the entire path in case the file is in a different place.

Thank you in advance anyone who decides to help me.

Comment: What language are you coding in? What have you tried already?

Comment: Your command line seems to be incomplete...

Comment: And what about the destination it's all the time F:\ ????

Answer (score 1):

Inside a batchfile, you can reference it's name with `%~f0`:

```
@echo off
echo My name is %~f0
```

It's directory is `%~dp0`, it's name.extension is `%~nx0`...

You can read about other modifiers with `help call`

Answer (score 0):

If your destination is always `F:\` :

```
@echo off
echo My working directory is : "%~dp0"
echo(
echo The Full Path of this file is :   "%~f0"
echo(
echo My Name is without extenstion is : "%~n0"
echo(
echo My Name is with extenstion is    : "%~nx0"
echo(
pause
cls
echo(
echo Copy /y "%~f0" F:\
echo(
If exist F:\ Copy /y "%~f0" F:\
echo(
pause
```